# What is the lashon in Rabbeinu Yona, Iggeres Hateshuva?

Tags: commentaries

What is the exact lashon of Rabbeinu Yona in Iggeres Hateshuva (Hadrash Hashlishi) that says, "they send the children to school and look after them when they return home. they influence their children with pleasant words and develop in them a desire to study torah. they protect them so that they will not waste time from their studies, and they teach them fear of heaven when they are young. ...the Jewish woman, the primary contribution to the child's early education, establishes the foundation of torah study and fear of God."

Comment: Hello User16618, welcome to Mi Yodeya!  Are you looking for a Hebrew translation of those words?

Answer (score 4):

In [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=7083&st=&pgnum=77&hilite=) edition it appears as follows (acc. to the seven-day division):

> מפני שהן שולחות בניהן לבית הספר, ומשימין עיניהן על בניהן שיתעסקו בתורה, ומרחמות עליהם בבואם מבית הספר, ומושכים לבם בדברים טובים שיהא חפצם בתורה, ושומרים אותם שלא יבטלו מן התורה, ומלמדים אותם יראת חטא בילדותם ... ונמצא לפי זה הנשים הצנועות מסבבות התורה והיקרה.

---

Note: from the (few) editions I've seen, the words "the primary contribution to the child's early education..." do not appear in the original Hebrew.